# while inside foreach or while in php does not work

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

The `while` loop works only for the first record of the `foreach` value. I couldn't understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach($country_array as $country_new)
{ 
    $result=mysql_query("select product.product_id,product.product_name from product left join country_iso_telcode on product.country=country_iso_telcode.country_name left join product_category_listing on product.product_id=product_category_listing.product_id where product.product_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]$search' and country_iso_telcode.region='$region' and product.country='$country_new'")or die("wrong query in search results displaying button results"); 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $product_id=$row['product_id'];
        $product_name=$row['product_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have asked this again now, deleting your earlier question..

Comment: You can not force anybody to answer you or put questions again and again to irritate themm..

Comment: Why would my question irritate anybody ? And I am not here forcing anybody.. My previous post was closed and became a junk with lot of irrelevant replies. What else can I do @Coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to put results in a array

```
$arr = array();
foreach($country_array as $country_new)
 { 
     $result=mysql_query("select product.product_id,product.product_name from product left join country_iso_telcode on product.country=country_iso_telcode.country_name left join product_category_listing on product.product_id=product_category_listing.product_id where product.product_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]$search' and country_iso_telcode.region='$region' and product.country='$country_new'")or die("wrong query in search results displaying button results"); 
$i = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $arr[$country_new]['product_id'][$i]=$row['product_id'];
    $arr[$country_new]['product_name'][$i]=$row['product_name'];
    $i++;
}

}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Ah thank u soooooooooooo much.... You saved me from lot more of thinking :) @Chandresh